# Como leer o extraer archivos dentro del src o JAR folder y ejecutarlos en el Sistema Operativo?

Tags: java

Este codigo me funciona, pero cuando agrego el programa bajador.exe, dentro de mi jar, en "/parseadores/bajador.exe", y cambio esas lineas para llamar al .exe desde dentro del jar, no funciona. ¿Alguien podria ayudarme en como deberia de hacerlo?. Estoy usando en todo momento el sistema operativo windows 10, y el editor eclipse. Gracias.

```
public void crearVideoEnCarpeta(){
    String portaPapeles = "";
    try {
        portaPapeles = (String) Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().getData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);
    } catch (HeadlessException | UnsupportedFlavorException | IOException e2) {
        e2.printStackTrace();
    }

    // aqui obtengo la ruta de donde se esta ejecutando el programa
    String rutaDondeSeEjecutaProgramaDescargador = new File(".").getAbsolutePath();
    // le quito el ultimo . y ultima barra \, osea los dos ultimos elementos, restandole -2 a su longitud
    rutaDondeSeEjecutaProgramaDescargador = rutaDondeSeEjecutaProgramaDescargador.substring(0, (rutaDondeSeEjecutaProgramaDescargador.length() - 2));
    String rutaDondeCopiare = rutaDondeSeEjecutaProgramaDescargador + "\\carpeta" + "\\videos";

    // antigua linea:
    //String rutaDondeDebeDeEstar = rutaDondeSeEjecutaProgramaDescargador + "\\carpeta\\bajador.exe " + "-o " + "\"" + rutaDondeCopiare + "\\%(title)s-%(id)s.%(ext)s\"";
    // nueva linea:
    String rutaDondeDebeDeEstarNueva = "/parseadores/bajador.exe" + " " + "-o " + "\"" + rutaDondeCopiare + "\\%(title)s-%(id)s.%(ext)s\"";

    try {
        String cmd2 = rutaDondeDebeDeEstarNueva + " " + portaPapeles;
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd2);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, cmd2);
        UIManager.put("OptionPane.minimumSize", new Dimension(262, 90));

    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.out.println(ioe);
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Que sistema operativo tienes? Por tu nick yo asumiría que estás usando wine

Comment: perdona por despistar, estoy usando un sistema operativo windows 10, y uso eclipse

Comment: ¿Puedes poner algo que compile? Es más tardado si no compila rehacer todo lo que tienes

Comment: Dentro de mi .jar hay un fichero .exe "/parseadores/bajador.exe", y quisiera llamar a ese .exe con parametros en java. Para el codigo que he escrito, podemos cambiar el bajador.exe por cualquier otro programa. Luego le siguen algunos argumentos y una ruta donde sacar la descarga. Al hacerlo me dio errores del tipo por ejemplo CreateProcess error = 2, El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado

Comment: Pero... ¿está el `.exe` en esa ruta? El SO no te va a ejecutar el `.exe` que está dentro del jar...

Comment: tu código no compila, ¿puedes poner un [mcve]?

Comment: Dentro del eclipse, en Project Explorer, en los paquetes del codigo fuente, NombreDelProyecto/src/parseadores/bajador.exe ahi tengo el fichero. Lo que hago es exportar todo mi proyecto, y entonces embebido en .jar que me crea eclipse, dentro va el .exe. Pero con el codigo de arriba, no me funciona. Intentare hacer otro ejemplo mucho mas reducido y que pueda mostrar que error me da y lo subo a este hilo para ver si alguien me ayuda en encontrar el error. Gracias a todos por intentar ayudarme.

Comment: como se indica si el `.exe` esta dentro del folder del codigo fuente este queda "bundled" dentro del `.jar` por tanto primero y antes de ejecutarlo debes extraerlo, para ello debes utilizar un input y un output stream (para leer y guardar el archivo respectivamente)  mediante el uso de: `this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/parseadores/bajador.exe")` y `Files.copy(InputStream in, Path target)` referencia: [java.nio.file.Files.copy()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy(java.io.InputStream,java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.CopyOption...))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En este caso lo que deseas Hacer es Executar un `.exe` que esta dentro del `.jar`, un archivo `.jar` es un archivo comprimido, el cual el OS no puede ejecutar archivos directamente.

es por tanto necesario que primero extraigas el .exe a un `Path` que el OS pueda ejecutar. para ello se Utiliza la Clase `java.lang.Class` y su metodo [`getResourceAsStream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)) para obtener un [`InputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) del cual podremos leer el contenido del archivo dentro del `.jar` hacia una Dirrecion que OS pueda Ejecutar, en el Siguiente Ejemplo, se Utiliza [`java.nio.file.Files.copy()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy(java.io.InputStream,java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.CopyOption...)) para copiar el contenido del archivo desde el recurso en el jar Hacia un Archivo Temporal:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class NewMain {

    /*extracts the resourse from the classpath to a temporal File on the OS tmp Folder.*/
    private static Path extractPayload(String resoursepath, String Filename, String extension) throws IOException {
        InputStream resourceStream = NewMain.class.getResourceAsStream(resoursepath);
        Path TmporalFile = Files.createTempFile(Filename, extension);
        Files.copy(resourceStream, TmporalFile, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
        return TmporalFile;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Path tmpfile = extractPayload("/resources/payload.exe", "bajador", ".exe");
            //imprima el Absolute Path. de donde esta el archivo temporal. 
            System.out.println(tmpfile.toAbsolutePath().toString());
            ProcessBuilder proc = new ProcessBuilder(tmpfile.toAbsolutePath().toString(), "-o", "param2", "param3", "param etc...");
            //redirija le input y output al Standar de Java. 
            proc.redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);
            proc.redirectInput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);

            Process pross = proc.start();
            //corra el .exe y espere a que termine
            pross.waitFor();
            //elimine el archivo temporal.
            if(Files.deleteIfExists(tmpfile))System.out.println("File Deleted.");
        } catch (IOException|InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(NewMain.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

ahora mi proyecto se ve algo asi:

[image: listadearchivos]

y el output:

```
run:
C:\Users\silencio\AppData\Local\Temp\bajador6041025182399461009.exe
//output del app
//output del app
File Deleted.
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 7 seconds)
```

Comment: muchisimas gracias