# Es correcta la ruta para leer este fichero en Java

Tags: java

Sería correcta la ruta que pongo en el FileReader para leer el fichero, ya que no para de ir al FileNotFoundException estando el método en el paquete lógica y el documento en Files todo dentro del src.

```
BufferedReader fichero = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Files/clientes.dat"));
            while (fichero.ready()) {
                linea = fichero.readLine();
                String[] trozos = linea.split("@");
                if(trozos[0] == usuarioCliente) {   //El Cliente ya esta Registrado
                    return true;
                }
```

Un saludo y muchas gracias.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2pay.png]

Comment: Las imágenes tienen una resolución muy pequeña, edita la pregunta e incluye el código para comprender la pregunta.

Comment: las imágenes son muy pequeñas, te recomiendo que hagas captura con "recortes" en el mismo windows, solo pon recortes y listo.

Comment: la ruta es efectivamente erronea:  "y el documento en Files todo dentro del src", por que?  puesto `"Files/clientes.dat"` no es un fichero detro del Src es un fichero que busca en el `current running folder` que es relativo a de donde se inicio el JVM. lo que necesitas es un Resource. para leer un archivo que esta dentro de SRC folder por favor refiere a esta respuesta: [ejecutar .exe desde dentro de .jar en java](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/225531/ejecutar-exe-desde-dentro-de-jar-en-java/225555#225555)

Comment: Posible duplicado de [ejecutar .exe desde dentro de .jar en java](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/225531/ejecutar-exe-desde-dentro-de-jar-en-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema que se presenta aqui es que esta intentanto leer un archivo desde el folder de donde se ejecuta el Applicativo Java. y no El recurso (todo lo que esta en el folder src, son recursos que quedaran empacados dentro de un .Jar) y en el caso de uso de un IDE el folder de ejecucion es relativo a donde se compile los .class por tanto:

basados en la respuesta de esta pregunta: [ejecutar .exe desde dentro de .jar en java](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/225531/ejecutar-exe-desde-dentro-de-jar-en-java)

tenemos que debemos leer el recurso para, ello se Utiliza la Clase [`java.lang.Class`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)) y su metodo [`getResourceAsStream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String))  para obtener un [`InputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html)

```
 /*NOTA: /Files/clientes.dat es el folder relativo a la raiz (src folder)
 NOTA#2: en mi caso utilizo NewMain que es el nombre de la clase que utilize como prueba,
 pero en tu caso debe tener el nombre de la clase donde se esta leyendo.
 o "this.getClass().getResourceAsStream()"
 */
 InputStream resourceStream = NewMain.class.getResourceAsStream("/Files/clientes.dat");
```

ahora para utilizarlo en un `BufferedReader` simplemente se hace un Wrap:

```
//donde "UTF-8" es el Character set. puede utilizarse otro o el que sea requerido por el archivo. 
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(resourceStream, "UTF-8"));
```